# Match a term ending with digit

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of words, with patterns either "term" or "termNUM", e.g. "term" or "term02".
I want to save all terms that ends with digit but remove the ones are purely alphabets.

I am totally new to regex, I tried few options, and get the following:

```
new_list = [x for x in old_list if re.match("[(^a-zA-Z_)\d]", x)]
```

It is not working, I know it only need a small tweak somewhere, but with my limited skill in regex, cannot do it quickly.

Tips are highly appreciated.

Comment: By placing into brackets `[]` your whole expression, you are a defining a set of characters. So your regex will only match the first `(` or `^`,  `_`, `)`, or a digit (`\d`) or a letter (`a-zA-Z`) in the string `x`. Taking some time to go through [this page](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) is really worth it, believe me ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
r".*\d"
```

That's any character (`.`), any number of times (`*`) followed by a digit (`\d`). Your list comprehension is correct.

You could also do

```
[x for x in old_list if x[-1].isdigit()]
```

assuming the empty string is not in the list. I'd prefer this option, as it's more explicit as to what it does.

Answer (score 3):

Why use regex, where you can simply check the last char is a digit or not. i.e.

```
new_list = [x for x in old_list if x[-1].isdigit()]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> list = ["term", "term2", "term200"]
>>> new_list = [x for x in list if re.match("^[a-zA-Z_]+\d+$", x)]
>>> new_list
['term2', 'term200']
```